# Import variable from Python script to Batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, import, python-import

I have a python script containing vraibles
example.py

```
"src = komponent/cool,
       komponent/raw"  /* path of source files */
```

and i have a batch file which needs to import the value of "src" for postporcessing
example.bat

```
--cs-include ='komponent/cool'* --cs-include ='komponent/raw'*
```

Is there any way to import directly between files (without using any other conversion) ?
"PyBat.bat" is one option but i am trying to figure out a better choice dont want to add on one more tool (not specifically)...as my project itself has too different files and interacting source.

Any help is appreciated..
Thank you in advance..!!!

Comment: Why not pass the values of src into the python file (and the batch file)?

Comment: Before compiling need to run the batch file..so necessary to includes.
My python file is so called static, the batch needs to be modified accordingly with once example.py changed

Comment: I don't think you can see if directly, without text parsing, but you can pass variables into a batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is...
1.set a argument in the python itself.
2.call the batch file from python script and along with pass the argument using 
  os.system(cmd) and cmd as a string.

It will set the path itself.

Answer (score 1):

**In Python**
Create a temp batch file in `%TEMP%\setvars.bat` containing `SET` commands to set environment vars.
You could use `subprocess.POpen` to run an `ECHO something > path` batch command so that `%TEMP%` can be used.

**In Batch**
`Call` the temp batch file : the vars are now available to use.